# React native clear Stack Navigator stack in bottom tab bars

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am developing an app which has bottom tab navigation. For implementing this , I've used `react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs`, which is working perfectly fine. Like I have 3 screens ,say Home, Profile and About in the bottom tab navigator. But in the Home screen I have multiple screens flow to be implemented. For that I used Stack Navigator, which is also working fine. So my app flow is like `Home-> Screen1-> Screen2-> Screen3` Where I'm facing problem is that suppose I'm on Screen3 and then I switch to Profile screen from bottom navigation, and then again switch to Home screen.

> I should be able to see Home Screen there but currently it shows Screen3

Following is my code:

MainTabs.js

```
 import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
    import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
    
    const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
    const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();
    const AboutStack = createStackNavigator();
    
    const HomeStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
      return (
        <HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false, initialRouteName: 'Screen1'}}>
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3}/>
        </HomeStack.Navigator>
      )
    }
    
    const ProfileStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
      return (
        <ProfileStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false, initialRouteName: 'Profile'}}>
          <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </ProfileStack.Navigator>
      )
    }
    
    const AboutStackScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
      return (
        <AboutStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false, initialRouteName: 'About'}}>
          <AboutStack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
        </AboutStack.Navigator>
      )
    }

const MainTabScreen = () => {
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        activeColor="#fff"
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
        labeled={false}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeStackScreen}
        />    
        
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={ProfileStackScreen}
        />

        <Tab.Screen
          name="About"
          component={AboutStackScreen}   
        />

      </Tab.Navigator>
  );

export default MainTabScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigation.navigate('routeName')` when you tap on your bottom tab navigator element. You have to register a route to the first screen of the stack, and from there you can go inside the stack as you like.

Answer (score 0):

[set unmountOnBlur options to true.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur)
If you don't mind this.

> Normally, we don't recommend enabling this prop as users don't expect their navigation history to be lost when switching tabs. If you enable this prop, please consider if this will actually provide a better experience for the user.

Another way is to pop the stack navigator when leaving screen3.